How can I fix vertical lines that appear on my LCD laptop screen
These lines keep appearing even in the BIOS menu so its not driver related. The weird thing is that these lines just start appearing on my screen, when I am using my laptop a solid color line appears on the screen at first they flicker then they just stay there and doesn't disappear.These lines are solid red, green and blue with a little hue to it.
Update: I forgot to mention but there is a huge green bar on the bottom of my screen (about 2-2.5 cm, on the bottom of the screen) it is translucent. The way it starts is that it just fades in and grows.

It's an hardware failure. You can't fix it.
The only fix is to replace the screen. Please contact customer support or other professional service if out of warranty.
